# POWER BI Creating visual using two dates from the same table

Tags: powerbi-desktop

I have a table of bugs that I want to create a line graph visual on:

```
| Id | Created Date | Closed Date |
|----|--------------|-------------|
| 1  | 01/01/2020   | 01/02/2020  |
| 2  | 01/01/2020   | 01/03/2020  |
| 3  | 02/01/2020   |             |
```

I want to create a line chart visual that shows per day how many bugs were created and how many were closed cumulatively (running total) using two lines.

Is it possible to create this from the one table (using two y-axis)? Do I need another table for the dates and what is the best way to create the relationship?

Answer (score 1):

This would be a great use case for a simple measure.

```
Running Total MEASURE = 
CALCULATE (
    COUNT(  'Table'[ID] ),
    FILTER (
        ALL ( 'Table' ),
        'Table'[Created Date] <= MAX (  'Table'[Created Date] )
    )
)
```

In the above DAX expression, simply plugin your created date and the bug ID where appropriate. Basically, it is counting the instance of each ID that occurs on or before every created date.

Let me know if this helps

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply. Would you suggest creating a measure also for the Closed Date? Also if I then had another column of "category" would I still be able to slice against this column if using measures?

Comment: Yes, I would create another measure, but this time replace “Created Date” with “Closed Date” to show the cumulative amount of cases closed as the DAX I provided into shows the cumulative amount of cases opened. Yes, this measure can be filtered by any column that is in your table or a table that has a relationship with your table.